# What's can I do if I just want to use python2 and without python3 to install some software?

Tags: python

It seems I have two versions of python on my ubuntu, now I have to install a software (DuctApe) which need a python environment 2.6 or higher (still not working with python 3), what should I do? Any need to uninstall python3?(someone has done that and the system was broken)

```
(base) yujie@yujie-Precision-7530:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.1

(base) yujie@yujie-Precision-7530:~$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.15rc1
```

Comment: Many tools in Ubuntu use python; so if you remove a python those tools will not work (ie. broken). You didn't give your release, as the use of python2 has reduced (ie. it's significance is greater in older releases).

Comment: ***I have to install a software in the environment of python2***: Can you please elaborate it little more may be with example?

Comment: Hi all, thanks very much. I won't uninstall python 3.     I was installing a software named "DuctApe" which need python 2.6 or higher but lower than version 3

Answer (score 3):

Python 2 and Python 3 exist quite happily together in Ubuntu. I would not recommend uninstalling either as some programs rely on Python 3 and a lot more rely on Python 2 so  you will break your system.

You can find python 3 here:

`/usr/bin/python3`

and Python 2 here

`/usr/bin/python2`

or here:

`/usr/bin/python`

Both are equivalent

To run a python 2 program simply type:

`python2 myprog.py`

or

`python myprog.py`

For Python 3 it's.

`python3 myprog.py`

Replacing `myprog.py` with the name of your program.

You can also make an executable shell script the simplest python 2 program is probably

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Python 2.7
print "Hello, World!"
```

And the simplest Python 3 program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Python 3.6
print ("Hello, World!")
```

In each case the first line tells it what interpreter to use.  The second line is not needed but is a comment I like to have so I know which version of Python I am using.  The last line should be obvious.

You also need to make the file executable to avoid the need to type 'python' or 'python3' as appropriate to the version of Python you are using.